# Why isn't AutoFixture working with the StringLength data annotation?

Tags: data-annotations, autofixture

I'm trying again to upgrade to [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) 2, and I'm running into a problem with the data annotations on my objects.  Here's an example object:

```
public class Bleh
{
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I'm attempting to create an anonymous `Bleh`, but the property with the annotation is coming up empty rather than being populated with an anonymous string.

```
[Test]
public void GetAll_HasContacts()
{
    var fix = new Fixture();
    var bleh = fix.CreateAnonymous<Bleh>();

    Assert.That(bleh.Bar, Is.Not.Empty);  // pass
    Assert.That(bleh.Foo, Is.Not.Empty);  // fail ?!
}
```

According to Bonus Bits, `StringLength` should be supported as of 2.4.0, though even if it wasn't supported I wouldn't expect an empty string.  I am using v2.7.1 from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture).  Have I missed some sort of customization or behavior that is necessary to create data-annotated objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this!

This behavior is by design (the reason for that is, basically, the description of the attribute itself).

By applying [StringLength(255)] on a data field it basically means that it is allowed to have 0 up-to 255 characters.

According to the description on msdn, the StringLengthAttribute Class:

- Specifies the maximum length of characters that are allowed in a data
  field. [[.NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)]
- Specifies the minimum and maximum length of characters that are
  allowed in a data field. [[.NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)]

The current version (2.7.1) is built on .NET Framework 3.5. The StringLengthAttribute class is supported as of 2.4.0.

That being said, the created instance is valid *(it's just that the second assertion statement isn't)*.

Here is a passing test that validates the created instance using the [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) class from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Ploeh.AutoFixture;

public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void GetAll_HasContacts()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var bleh = fixture.CreateAnonymous<Bleh>();

        var context = new ValidationContext(bleh, serviceProvider: null, items: null);

        // A collection to hold each failed validation.
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        // Returns true if the object validates; otherwise, false.
        var succeed = Validator.TryValidateObject(bleh, context, 
            results, validateAllProperties: true);

        Assert.That(succeed, Is.True);  // pass
        Assert.That(results, Is.Empty); // pass
    }

    public class Bleh
    {
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Update 1**:

While the created instance is *valid*, I believe that this could be adjusted to pick a random number inside the range (0 - maximumLength) so the user never gets an empty string.

I have also created a discussion at the forum [here](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/discussions/283845).

**Update 2**:

The original test case will now pass if you upgrade to AutoFixture version 2.7.2 (or newer).

```
[Test]
public void GetAll_HasContacts()
{
    var fix = new Fixture();
    var bleh = fix.CreateAnonymous<Bleh>();

    Assert.That(bleh.Bar, Is.Not.Empty);  // pass
    Assert.That(bleh.Foo, Is.Not.Empty);  // pass (version 2.7.2 or newer)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I suppose the fact that (valid) empty strings were causing us trouble suggests that we're misusing AutoFixture a bit, but I'm nonetheless grateful for the speedy update.  We'll give it a try ASAP!